# How can I declare a typescript interface as a class attribute

Tags: typescript, class, interface

I have defined an interface like this:

```
export interface Donor{
    donorName: string;
    donorId: string;
    donorPassword:string
    donorAge: number
    fitnessReport: string
    physicianApproval: string
}
```

I would like to use a variable of this interface type as a private class attribute in the below class

```
class SawtoothService {

  //Donor component
  private currentDonor: <Donor>;

  public setDonor(currentDonor) {
    this.currentDonor = currentDonor;
   }

}
```

I will be setting it to a implementation done somewhere else by calling the function setDonor.

This is throwing error in the line

```
private currentDonor: <Donor>;
```

Comment: `private currentDonor: Donor;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand a little on the comment that gives the correct solution, the `<` and `>` characters are used for specifying [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html)*, for example if you had multiple donors you might use `Array<Donor>`.

In this case you just have a plain old `Donor` instance, so you don't need the triangle brackets. It should be the same format as your `donorName: string` line, expect the type here is `Donor` not `string`.

* They're also used for greater/less than comparison, of course, but I'm sure you know that already and it's not relevant here.